# Trying to make method for hibernate criteria search

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to make method for hibernate criteria search for user login.In this case I can not understand how to set the

```
 add(Restrictions.eq(propertyName, value));
```

for the method. I know `propertyName` should be the `column name`. but how can I get this and are there any mistake in code.

This is my servlet

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String email=req.getParameter("email");
            String password=req.getParameter("password");
            
            String [] arr = {email,password};
                creatreCriteria(Account.class);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                addeqResrictions("colum name", arr.length);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

this is my session class.

```
 public static Criteria creatreCriteria(Class PC){
        getSession().createCriteria(PC);
        return criteria;
   }
    public static  SimpleExpression addeqResrictions(String p, Object v){
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(p, v));
        return simpleExpression;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why would you create a method just to add _eq_ restrictions?

Comment: because I want to create one method for all eq.restrictions of my code.

Comment: So what about _ge, gt, le, and, ilike, not, or, isEmpty, between, size_, etc.... are you going to create methods for each one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to parse a Map containing the values. Your method should look like this.

```
public static void addeqRestrictions(HashMap<String, Object> r) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : r.entrySet()) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }
}
```

Usage,

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
map.put("ColName", object1);
map.put("ColName", object2);
map.put("ColName", object3);

addeqRestrictions(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

A property name should be not a column name, but a property name (a field name) of the persistent class. So if you have a class `User` with a field `login`.

```
@Entity
class User {

  @Column
  private String login;

}
```

You can use this criteria

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(User.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("login", someLogin);
```